# How do I get a type argument from a Type variable?

Tags: c#

I need to call a method defined as:

```
public static T Deserialize<T>(Stream source)
```

In my code below I have determined the type:

```
string serializedObj = objbyte;

var typeSeperatorIndex = serializedObj.IndexOf(TypeSeperator);
var type = Type.GetType(serializedObj.Substring(0, typeSeperatorIndex));
var serialized = serializedObj.Substring(typeSeperatorIndex + 1);


byte[] byteAfter64 = Convert.FromBase64String(serialized);
MemoryStream afterStream = new MemoryStream(byteAfter64);

var result = Serializer.Deserialize<xxxxx>(afterStream);
return result;
```

I need to supply the xxxxx type argument to the Deserialize<> method. How do I get this from my **type** variable?

Comment: Try searching, see [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/232535/how-do-i-use-reflection-to-call-a-generic-method).

Comment: I did search but did not come across that post.  Do you know if reflection is the only way to do this as it seems rather cumbersome and inefficient?

Comment: It's the first Google hit for "C# call generic method with Type", if that helps. And no, there's no other way: you have runtime information (a `Type`) and you need compile-time information (generic parameters). You can't do that without reflection.

Comment: That will teach me to use the SO search box instead of Google ;-)